# Dynamic if statement evaluation problem with string comparison

Tags: java

I tried the example given in [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=780576&tstart=67605)
to create if statement dynamically using [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/home.html). But it is not working fine. Instead of using "age" variable as integer, i have used string in the below example. I am getting "fail" as answer instead of "success".

Can anyone help me?

```
/*
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Main {
  public static String d;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try {
      String age = "30";

      String cond = "age==30";


      Interpreter i = new Interpreter();

      i.set("age", age);

      System.out.println(" sss" + i.get("age"));

      if((Boolean)i.eval(cond)) {
        System.out.println("success");
      } else {
        System.out.println("fail");
      }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose either numeric comparison or String comparison.  This requires using a compatible condition and type for age.

Numeric:

```
  int age = 30;
  String cond = "age==30";
```

String:

```
  String age = "30";
  String cond = "age.equals(\"30\")";
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone. For string comparison, can we do something like this?

String age = "30";
String cond = "age==\"30\"";

or As syntactic mentioned below, it is not possible?

Comment: Mani, it works when I modify the code and run it, but I think it's not guaranteed to work in the general case if the `String` you are comparing to isn't interned.

Comment: @Mani, I'm updating my answer with the one to your question

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two objects with the == operator, you're comparing two *references*. You're essentially asking whether two different names refer to the same object in memory.

To compare the actual *values* of objects, you need to use the `equals()` method. This is something that's very important to understand about Java.

Comment: 30 is not an object, it's an int.

Comment: @Matthew, I ran the code locally and making the change in my answer yielded "success".  I think it is in fact an object.

Comment: @Phil, as I said, 30 is not an object.  "30" is.

Comment: @Matthew, sorry I misunderstood the point of your comment then.  I thought you were correcting @Syntactic's answer.

Comment: @Phil, I am correcting it.  The condition in the OP's code compares age to 30, an int.  So it's not correct to say "you're comparing two references."

Answer (score 0):

You are using `==` to compare string types.  Try using `age.equals("30")` instead.

**EDIT**: to show it working

If you use this as the definition of `cond`:

```
String cond = "age.equals(\"30\")";
```

Output:

```
 sss30
success
```

---

In response to the question about using `=="30"` instead, here is the answer to that:

If your `String age` is interned, because it is a compile-time constant for example, then it *could* be true.

```
final String age = "30";
```

However if you explicitly `new` the `String` or it is otherwise not interned, then it will be false.

```
String age = new String("30");
```

You can run both examples to see this in effect.  Possibly - you may get `fail` for both.

Now, just because interning exists doesn't mean one should ever rely on it for comparing `String` types.  The `==` operator should only be used to compare primitives to each other, and to compare reference types to see if they point to the same object, so for reference types we could say it is seeing if two objects are **identical** instead of **equal**.

Sometimes through the magic of the JVM and JDK, `String` and other primitive wrappers like `Integer` may be comparable with `==`, but the situations for this are limited and not reliable.

Comment: I tried by declaring age as final String age = "30"; but it is giving me false only.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the caveat - never rely on string interning!  Only primitives should be compared using `==` even if you strongly suspect that due to interning two `String` objects should be identical.  On my machine and JVM they came out ok and giving `success`, but that's not guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @Mani, the only line I changed was the `final String age = "30";` above.  But I just edited my answer to give the reason that on my machine it came out `success` but on yours it was `fail`.  The bottom line is use `==` for primitives, and `.equals(..)` for reference types, even if the possibility exists for `==` to work.  It's not portable or guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew Flaschen is correct. As an aside, you can simplify your output as follows:

```
System.out.println(cond + " is " + i.eval(cond));
```

which produces

> age == 30 is true

Answer (score 0):

The string compare with "==" in the bsh interpreter is not working like expected.

It is working like that: (copied from the link bellow)

```
    Beanshell handles '==' like java and not e.g. like JavaScript. That means you've got to use "equals" to compare instances.
    bsh % "abc" == "abc"; => true
    bsh % "abc" == new String("abc"); => false
    bsh % "abc".equals("abc"); => true
    bsh % "abc".equals(new String("abc")); => true
```

further information here: https://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/issues/detail?id=86

So you have to use the ".equal()", or compile your own bsh version, like i did it.
(read the complete issue above)