# How to create dynamic IF statements? reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic, if-statement

Is it possible with reflection to create a dynamic IF statement?

I have seen examples with BeanShell (like this: [Dynamic if statement evaluation problem with string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838801/dynamic-if-statement-evaluation-problem-with-string-comparison)) but i would like to know if it was possible to do it without BeanShell, and be pointed to some examples to adapt to my needs.

Basically i have a statement of the form: A operator B.

A and B can be numbers (Doubles or ints) or strings, but always A is the same type as B.
operator can be !=, ==, >=, >, <= ,<, and even others which behavior may be defined trough a class of their own, another reason why i will use reflection, since i can take that string and use reflection to invoke the appropriate method.

I want (must) to avoid branching "if" and "switch" because the variations are too many and will change constantly with user generated input.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not use the Strategy design pattern?

Comment: Dynamically creating IFs is not the way to go with this, whatever you're doing

Comment: I am literally reading conditions from a custom script language. They have the form: functionA operator functionB. The operators is limited now but could grow. I would love to be able to read the strings, and evaluate the expression somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection won't help. Reflection gives you information about your code structure (classes, methods, attributes), but it doesn't allow you to change and update existing code.

Don't try to generate new code, try instead of adding a way for users to change the behaviour of your app depending on their input.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. Post some examples of user input and expected behaviour to help narrow the options down. But here is a few things that might help you in your task:

- Have a user interface that helps your user select the time of the operands, with text fields for values, and a dropdown box for the operator. Simple solution, but I wouldn't recommend it as it may add complexity to the user interface.
- Write a parser for your expressions. Writting a simple parser for this very simple language (A operator B) should be doable in reasonable time.
- Domain Specific Languages. Allows the users of your application to write some scripts that get interpreted by your application and respond in some way. You could imagine a DSL consisting in simple comparisons, and the results will influence the behaviour of your app. Have a look at Groovy, it is a good language for this use case.

Comment: Thank you. Everyone else misunderstood what i wanted to achieve, since they simply gave versions of what i wanted to avoid: hardcoding the operators themselves. I wanted to know if there was a way to create a string with the proper java syntax from a scripted language and evaluate that expression, like in this post using BeanShell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838801/dynamic-if-statement-evaluation-problem-with-string-comparison. problem is BeanShell seams to be dead and i don't want do add that to my project. Actually your bullet point 1 and 2 are already part of my program :P

Comment: The reflection part was beacause in the BeanShell tread i linked they used it, and i use it myself for a part of the program that calls the apropiate methods depending on what the script language says. Example: Count(a.value,set)>=value(4). Count simply finds how many a.value exist in set and returns a number. using reflection i call the appropriate method after parsing the scripted file.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a factory that returns the correct operator for the given input.

```
public class OperatorFactory {
  private static final Map<String, Operator<?>> OPERATORS = new HashMap<String, Operator<?>>();

  static {
    OPERATORS.put("<Number", new LessThanNumOperator());
    OPERATORS.put("==Number", new EqualToNumOperator());
    OPERATORS.put("<String", new LessThanStringOperator());
    ...
  }

  public static Operator<?> getOperator(String someUserSpecifiedOp, Class<?> paramType) {
    String key = someUserSpecifiedOp;
    if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
      key += "Number";
    } else if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
      key += "String";
    }
    return OPERATORS.get(key);
  }
}

public interface Operator<T> {
  public boolean execute(T lhs, T rhs);
}

public class LessThanNumOperator implements Operator<Number> {
  public boolean execute(Number lhs, Number rhs) {
     return  lhs.doubleValue() < rhs.doubleValue();
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
OperatorFactory.getOperator(userDesignatedOperation, lhs.getClass()).execute(lhs, rhs);
```

Comment: Note that this is uses both the factory and strategy design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a interface like this

```
public interface MyComparator
{
    public boolean matches(String operator);
    public boolean compare(String a, String b);
}
```

Then you could make how many classes you want all implementing the interface like this

```
public class MyEquals implements MyComparator
{
    @Override
    public boolean matches(String operator)
    {
    return "==".equals(operator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean compare(String a, String b)
    {
    return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

and load them like this:

```
Class compClass = Class.forName(classname);
MyComparator comp = (MyComparator)compClass.newInstance();
```

you could so prepare a list of all available operators and iterate over it and even have the list of operators configured on a properties file.

Comment: The problem with this is that it implies hardcoding the operator, which would be almost the same as just creating a big switch(operator) with a case for each one i wanted. I even have a class operator that has an int ID for each one, but i was looking for a more flexible solution.

Comment: Who is going to define operators behaviour? You (the programmer) or the user?

Comment: \@Maxx: Excellent question, the first batch of function will be defined by me (the programmer), but i want to leave the door open for users to extend a Function class i created and add their own. Functionally they write the class, they add the name of a configuration file, and it would be possible to create conditions using that new function. But i think i will change the specification to be less ambitious, i am running out of time.